# how do i backup s3 or is it possible to backup s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

- does s3 have snapshots? how should I solve a problem where something would, for example, delete all my s3 data, how do I backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple options.
 1. Enable versioning on your bucket. Every version of the objects will be retained. Deleting an object will just add a "delete marker" to indicate the object was deleted. You will pay for the storage of all the versions. Note that versions can also be deleted.
 2. If you are just worried about deletion you can add a bucket policy to prevent deletion. You can also use some of the newer hold options.
 3. You can use cross region replication to copy the objects to a bucket in a different region and optionally a different account.

Comment: what about if i want to create a snapshot so that i can replicate the state? you know like i could with zipping a folder and extracting it locally on my computer